# An SQL query to fetch all the cities that are, as the bird flies, within a distance from a given coordinate?

Tags: mysql, sql, math, sqlite

I'm currently using this query to get a town inside my DB by giving a coordinate :

```
SELECT *
FROM citiesTable
WHERE latitude  >= ? AND latitude  <= ?
  AND longitude >= ? AND longitude <= ?;
```

This code works well and do I want but sometimes the query doesn't match anything... 
So, in this case, I would put a bird distance to this query in order to get adjacent town.
Any suggestion on how can I do that ?

Comment: The missing `>=` in `latitude >= ?` was just at typo, right?

Comment: @Gabe : a bird distance is a distance between two coordinate with no cars, bicycle, etc road consideration. Sorry, I badly expressed myself.

Comment: http://mapsof.net/distance-calculator/Bird

Comment: @muistooshort : my mistake, thanks for having corrected me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for "distance from longitude and latitude" gave a link to http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html which specifies this code for calculating the distance:

```js
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```

A couple more minutes of searching led to http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html

That page is chock-full of information. Here's a simple (but inefficient) solution, assuming your town is at `$lon,$lat` and `$R` is 6371 (which is km), and finally that you want the cities to be within `$rad` of your town:

```
Select ID, Postcode, Lat, Lon, 
       acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))*$R As D
From MyTable 
Where acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))*cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))*$R < $rad
```

Comment: thanks for this perfect answer! I accepted it because I don't think I'll find better. But I still have a problem, I use SQLite and it appears (because of mobile application) this snippset of code doesn't appear to work.. have you a suggestion ? Thanks again anyway

Comment: I'm sorry, you specified the "mysql" tag in your question, which thought meant you needed a solution in mysql. Try looking for how to get the same math functions in SQLite. [few seconds search] It seems that you need to create a custom function. Here's the first link I hit http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71 - go forth and experiment!